# Codeigniter codehint for language

Tags: codeigniter, netbeans

Has I have been building my codeigniter application in Netbeans and I have thought of an idea that would be very useful to have. I don't think it is possible but I thought i'd ask.

So when I am using the language helper function `lang('');` it's annoying to go back and forth between my `views/controllers` and the lang files to make sure that I have the correct keys.

It would be nice for a code hint on that function that would list all keys and their values. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this? It know it might not be possible but I thought I'd ask either way.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible you just have to develop it!  You can use the Code Completion API available here:
http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-code-completion.html

I am not sure if there exists one already but a quick google search didn't return exactly what you're after.  It might be too much effort for very little payoff to develop it yourself just for this one application.

Comment: It would be for any websites I build with codeigniter. I have a team of developers that work under me so it would be something we would use often.

Comment: Then it might be a good idea for one of your developers to make this a little side project to help your application development down the road.